# Error while deleting a double linked cycle list

Tags: c++, pointers, delete-operator

Well I need a well designed double linked cycle list and as there's no std I built this class below. The problem is that when exiting the program or fully deleting the CycleList I get an error: Access violation reading location 0xfeeeff22. (MVS 2010)

The funny part is that everything seems to be deleted properly when I debug. (And those 3 couts in the destructor perfectly print...).

Any ideas?

```
class CycleList{
public:

struct Node{
    static int s_size;
    static int e_size;
    IwPoint3d P;
    IwVector3d N;
    Node* next;
    Node* prev;

    Node(IwPoint3d _P, IwVector3d _N){
        P = _P;
        N = _N;
        next = this;
        prev = this;
        ++Node::s_size;
    }

    Node(IwPoint3d _P, IwVector3d _N, Node* _prev, Node* _next){
        P = _P;
        N = _N;
        prev = _prev;
        next = _next;
        prev->next = this;
        next->prev = this;
        ++Node::s_size;
    }

    ~Node(){
        prev->next = next;
        next->prev = prev;
        --Node::s_size;
    }
private:
    Node(const Node& rhs){} //copy forbidden
    Node operator=(const Node&){}
};

Node* current;
int size;

CycleList(IwPoint3d P, IwVector3d N){
    current = new Node(P,N);
    size = 1;
}

~CycleList(){
    while(!empty()){
        delete current->next;
    }
    cout << "I'm here" << endl;
    delete current;
    cout << "and here.." << endl;
    size = 0;
    cout << "and even here..." << endl;
}

bool empty() const{
    return current == current->next;
}

void insert_front(IwPoint3d P, IwVector3d N){
    new Node(P,N,current,current->next);
    ++size; 
}

void insert_back(IwPoint3d P, IwVector3d N){
    new Node(P, N,current->prev,current);
    ++size;
}

void delete_front(){
    if(!empty()){
        delete current->next;
        --size;
    }
}
void delete_back(){
    if (!empty()){
        delete current->prev;
        --size;
    }
}

IwPoint3d &front(){
    return current->next->P;
}

IwPoint3d &back(){
    return current->prev->P; 
}

void print(){
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i){
        cout << '(' << current->P.x << ", " << current->P.y << ", " << current->P.z << ')' << endl;
        current = current->next;
    }
}
};
```

Ok, I found it. I had a std::List of this CycleList that got them by copy and I was deleting them and then at the end of the program when deleting this list was probably following pointers that were no longer pointing anywhere...

I had something like which crashes at the end of the function:

```
CycleList initial_front(hex1_p,hex1_n);
initial_front.print();

list<CycleList> Fronts;

Fronts.push_back(initial_front);

while (Fronts.size() > 0){
    CycleList current_front = Fronts.front();
    Fronts.pop_front();
    current_front.print();
}
```

But something like that is working:

```
CycleList initial_front(hex1_p,hex1_n);
initial_front.print();

list<CycleList*> Fronts;

Fronts.push_back(&initial_front);

while (Fronts.size() > 0){
    CycleList* current_front = Fronts.front();
    Fronts.pop_front();
    current_front->print();
}
```

If you've got a best way of doing that, I'll be glad to know about it.

Comment: so `std::dequeue` doesn't fullfil your needs?

Comment: @Claptrap, he has no access to stl.

Comment: @utnapistim oh, i read it as there is no double linked cycle list in std when in fact you can simulate that with dequeue

Comment: @AbstractKeewee, I can see no reason for your crash. Are you sure it is caused in the destruction of this list? What happens if you try this?  `int main() { { IwPoint3d p; IwVector3d v; CycleList cl{p, v}; } std::cout << "past scope" << std::endl; };`? Do you see the last message?

Comment: It would be useful if you created a complete testcase that we can take, compile, run and see the crash for ourselves. Ideally it would be on something like ideone so people dont even need to compile to see it themselves.

Comment: @utnapistim: In fact I have access to std, but it doesn't have a doublelinked cycle list. Ifthat's not woking I'll use dequeue o.o I'll try that code too.

I'll post too some test case ;)

Comment: Just found the problem and edited the question. Much thanks guys ñ.ñ

Answer (score 1):

On a first look, this seems to be a double free if you don't advance current.

```
while(!empty()){
    delete current->next;
}
```

Comment: Nah, that works perfectly I think. Look at the destructor for Node, it puts pointers in the right way before destroying Node so that works ;)